# What is the use of web.config file in side of Laravel public folder

Tags: laravel

- Once we type the www.domain_name.com/web.config in the browser it downloading the web.config file.
- Is there any vulnerability and what is the use of web.config file in side of Laravel public folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `web.config` file is used by IIS which is the webserver software from Microsoft. It is basically the `.htaccess` of the Microsoft ecosystem which together with the [rewrite plugin](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) mentioned in [the file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/ebc6f6e2c794b07c6d432483fd654aebf2ffe222/public/web.config#L3) used to make the pretty urls work under IIS.

There is no harm in having it but no harm in removing it too if you are not using IIS for serving your application.

Comment: Is it a default file which created once the Laravel project is created?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in the [`laravel/laravel`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) repo (which is the "template" for a Laravel project): https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/v5.8.17/public

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. It's really help full.

Comment: No problem, glad I could clarify!

Comment: How do I prevent access to download this web.config file

Comment: If you are using IIS this file shouldn't be accessible because it's used by IIS, but if you are not the file can be accessed, simplest way is to just delete it from the public folder as long as you are not using IIS as a webserver you can safely remove the file.

Comment: Just an FYI for passers by and Windows developers who like to set up Laravel on IIS for development purposes...  The `web.config` file has disappeared from the `laravel/laravel` git-repo since v7.  `.htaccess` is still included up to v9 (even though most people seem to use Nginx these days). @Alex 's link points to the v5 repo, but even this version of `web.config` file is forwardly compatible to IIS 10 (Windows 11, Nov 2022). Simply copy/paste it into your project's `/public` directory.